# Table created with php array. How do i get each individual value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Ok, so I have a page that users upload docs from. I put them in a folder and then update a table to show where these docs live. Now, when I go to an edit page I query that database using PHP and echo the location of those files. I'm trying to figure out a way to delete files. I know I need to unlink, but the problem I'm having is I can't seem to figure out how to get the location of each individual file. Here is the code I'm using to get the file locations.

```
 <?php

                $sql = 'select trnum, trseq, trfnam, trfloc, podnum
                        from bd.bdvdocs
                        where trnum = ' . $_GET['trnum'];

                $result = db2_exec($conn, $sql);

                if ($result) {
                    while ($row = db2_fetch_array($result)) {


                       echo"<tr>";
                       echo "<td><a href='" . $row[3] . $row[0] . '/' . $row[2] . "'>$row[2]</a>        </td>";


                       echo"</tr>";
                    }
                }

                ?>
```

[image: This is what I get]
If I add a button to the right of each link and use jquery to get var, it only comes back with the value of the first link. If I click on the second button the page bombs out.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or something with the output/markup? Would probably help someone give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: You seem to be asking about JavaScript code, but I don't see any in your question.

Comment: Be careful, this code is absolutely not protected against SQL Injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<td>` a class ( `echo "<td class = "whatever">`... ), create a named table with tbody and stuff and by using jQuerys closest() function you should then be able to find the values:

```
$('#name_of_table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
       alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.whatever').html());
});
```

Create table like:

```
<table id="name_of_table"><tbody>
```

`<?php`

```
while ($row = db2_fetch_array($result)) {


                       echo"<tr>";
                       echo "<td class="whatever"><a href='" . $row[3] . $row[0] . '/' . $row[2] . "'>$row[2]</a>        </td>";


                       echo"</tr>";
                    } ?> </tbody></table>
```

Comment: When I do this echo "<td class="whatever"><a href='" . $row[3] . $row[0] . '/' . $row[2] . "'>$row[2]</a></td>"; I get this whole string back. But, this works like a charm echo "<td class="whatever">$row[3]$row[0]/$row[2]</td>";